# roll_meanr returns NA with group_by()

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

For a while, I've been using `RcppRoll`'s `roll_meanr()` function to get rolling averages. However, now, when I use it on a `grouped data frame` after `group_by()`, I'm returned with all `NA`s.

I have before used `roll_meanr()` successfully with as many groupings as below. I know it works by removing one grouping, but I don't see why this can't be solved or work with the groupings I use below.

Here's an example of this problem.

```
# Create test data and turn into data frame
df <- cbind(
  c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
  c("cali", "bong", "bong", "cali", "neva", "cali", "neva", "neva", "bong"),
  c(32, 22, 22, 00, 32, 32, 21, 21, 43),
  c("kingdom", "democratic", "democratic", "kingdom", "democratic",
"democratic", "kingdom", "kingdom", "democratic")) %>%
  as.data.frame()

# Set column names
colnames(df) <- c("days", "names", "numbers", "category")

# Set numbers as numeric
df$numbers <- as.numeric(df$numbers)

# Group and get rolling average
df %>%
  group_by(names, category, days) %>%
  mutate(rolling = RcppRoll::roll_meanr(numbers, 2))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups:   names, category, days [9]
  days  names numbers category   rolling
  <fct> <fct>   <dbl> <fct>        <dbl>
1 1     cali        4 kingdom         NA
2 2     bong        3 democratic      NA
3 3     bong        3 democratic      NA
4 4     cali        1 kingdom         NA
5 5     neva        4 democratic      NA
6 6     cali        4 democratic      NA
7 7     neva        2 kingdom         NA
8 8     neva        2 kingdom         NA
9 9     bong        5 democratic      NA
```

Comment: You have only one observation per group `df %>% group_by(names, category, days) %>% summarise(n = n())`

Comment: Completely missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

akrun's answer (from the comments):

"You have only one observation per group"

```
df %>% group_by(names, category, days) %>% summarise(n = n())
```